# Permalink is not working on github page [jekyll]

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am building my homepage with jekyll and github-pages.
All is going fine, including the permalink of the markdown files in the submodule of my repository.

However: there is one page that is not showing at the permalink address:
build page: https://atlassianps.github.io/docs/ConfluencePS/
source page: https://github.com/lipkau/ConfluencePS/blob/0750be31ebed41e3613f8ccba7173c184e869217/docs/commands/about_ConfluencePS.md

What am I doing that is keeping that `permalink` from working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the way it is rendered on GitHub..[image]

ensure that:

- there is absolutely **nothing** before the front matter dashes
- you're file is saved properly with `UTF-8` encoding.. i.e. there is no BOM characters there.

Comment: Thank you.The file was in UTF-8 with BOM